# Unable to pass custom Matrix4 to GLSL as a uniform

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl, matrix

I am fairly new to graphics programming and I am trying to pass a custom Matrix4 (non-glm) to my vertex shader by using a uniform.

```
    Matrix44 transform;  //creates a 4x4 identity matrix
    transform.SetTranslation(Vector3(0.5f, 0.3f, 0.0f));
    GLint transformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "transformation");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation, sizeof(transform), GL_FALSE, &transform.m[0][0]);
```

Above is the code which I am using to send the matrix to the shaders.

(the .m allows me to access the matrix as a 2D array of 4x4 floats);

This is how my vertex shader looks like:

```
#version 430 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{                   
   gl_Position = transform*vec4(position,1.0f);     
}
```

When I run it, I don't get anything drawn on my screen, except the background color.

Below is the matrix which I send to the shader. I am using column major, so as far as I've read this should be the translation part of the 4x4. I've also tried transposing the matrix with no luck whatsoever.

[image]

The last clue I have is that the values which I am sending are 0s. I came to this conclusion because I tried playing with the fragment shader and I set the color to be equal to the last column from the uniform mat4:

```
#version 430 core
out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
 color = vec4(transform[0][3],transform[1][3], transform[2][3], transform[3][3]);   
}
```

Which gives me a black triangle i.e. the color vec4 is filled with 0s.

[image]

I apologize in advance if the question is too noob-ish but I've been struggling with this for several days and I could not find a way to run it :(

Any advise would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLocation, sizeof(transform), GL_FALSE, &transform.m[0][0]);
> ```

The [second parameter to `glUniformMatrix`](http://docs.gl/gl4/glUniform) is not the number of bytes in the data. OpenGL can figure that out from the `4fv` part of the command (a 4x4 matrix of `GLfloat`s). The second parameter is the number of *matrices* you're sending to that uniform, in case it is an array of `mat4`s.

So that value ought to be 1. You almost certainly got a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error from calling it with `sizeof(transform)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nicol. I`ve fixed the argument mistake and found out the root cause. I have specified 'transformation' as my uniform value and was trying to use 'transform'.... It works llike a charm now.